# SharePoint List Column Formula using YEAR and LOOKUP

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have created a column named `Quarter` (Type - Calculated) in my List that I want to calculated based on a Date column (ex. 01/26/15). My formula is as follows:

`="FY"&YEAR([Date]+274)&" Q"&LOOKUP(MONTH([Date]),{0,4,7,10;2,3,4,1})`

I get a message

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

I have tested the formula in excel and it works perfectly. I believe `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `LOOKUP` functions are all supported in SharePoint.

Am I missing a syntax error here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below formula

```
=CONCATENATE("FY",YEAR(Date+274)," Q", IF(Month(Date)>10,1,IF(Month(Date)>7,4,IF(Month(Date)>4,3,2))))
```

**Logic**

1. `CONCATENATE` can be used to form formatted TEXT
2. First find FY - So here we can use the same Excel formula `FY + Year(Date+274)`
3. To calculate Quarter - We need to use `IF` statements. It take form `If(Condition,TRUE,FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember Lookup being an allowable formula in the calculated column syntax. I think you'd need to replace those with Ifs. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx) is my go to article for calculated column references.

If you break the formula into separate pieces, you should see it work for both year and quarter. To make it easier, you can create the if branch in a separate column, then just merge in that column into your final formula. nesting ifs can get squirrelly to read.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eric that LOOKUP is not a usable formula for calculated column. This is the formula I have used for displaying "Q# YYYY" format for a date column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(TestDate),"",(CONCATENATE("Q"&(INT((MONTH(TestDate)-1)/3)+1)&" "&(YEAR(TestDate)))))
```